# Why does Arduino need to be reset between use (Node.js + node-serialport + socket.io)

Tags: node.js, sockets, serial-port, arduino

I'm working on a little project where I'm using a web interface (node + [socket.io](http://socket.io/) + [node-serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport)) to send data to a serial port which is then read by the Arduino to set a pin HIGH, powering an led (which I will later convert to model rocket ignition system).

What I have below works, but there are two fundamental issues I've encountered that I would like to resolve in order to sure up the reliability:

- Why do I have to reset the Arduino between each page load / serial connection in order for this to work?
- Why is that when I don't limit how many times the sketch loop is executed (via x), it continuously prints data to the serial port, even if I only sent a single char?

**Sketch**

```
int led = 8;
int x = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if(x < 1) {
    if(Serial.available() > 0) {

      Serial.print(1);

      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);

      x++;
    }
  }
}
```

**app.js** (shortened for brevity)

```
socket.on('launch', function(data) {
  for(var i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    socket.emit('countdown', { count: i });

    if(i !== 1) {
      sleep(1);
    }
  }

  serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/tty.usbserial-A6004amR", { 
    baudrate: 9600
  });

  serialPort.on('open', function (err) {
    console.log('port opened... Press reset on the Arduino.');

    serialPort.on('close', function (err) {
      console.log('port closed');
    });

    serialPort.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('error: ' + err);
    });

    serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
      // keeps getting 'data' events when x doesn't limit the loop
      console.log('data received: ' + data);
    }); 

    serialPort.write(2, function(err, result) {
      console.log('sent ' + result +  ' chars.');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, for the second problem the reason it continuously prints is that you check for whether any data is available or not on the serial port by `Serial.available()` but since you do not read the data, the data remains available next time you reach to the statement. A `Serial.read()` function can be used to read the data available and remove it from the serial buffer. Now, to mitigate the problem of continuous printing, you have introduced the variable `x` and this is the root cause behind your first problem. Once the value of `x` is incremented, it does not get reset to 0 till you do a hardware level reset of arduino. So could you please try the following sketch and let me know if it works or not? Thanks.

```
int led = 8;

void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
      Serial.read(); //-> if you comment this line out, you can see continuously printing.
      Serial.print(1);

      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);

  }
}
```

Comment: Won't this create an endless loop? You're reading if there is data, and then you print 1, which will then cause the loop to execute again because there is data (1) available in the buffer.

Comment: No.The pin RX is used to receive data from the host and the pin TX is used to transmit data. So read/available look on the RX pin whereas print writes to the TX pin.